# C++ for loop outputs different results with one array than multiple arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I can't understand why the outputs are different when I put 1 array into a very simple for loop and when I put two arrays into it.

```
int arrR[100];
int arrN[100];

//function to run the simulation
void runsim(){
    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
        arrN[i] = i;
        arrR[i] = i;
    }
}


//function to print the array
void printarr(int x[100]){
    for(int i=0;i <= 100;i++){
        cout << x[i] << ", ";
    }
cout << endl;
}


int main(){
runsim();
printarr(arrR);
printarr(arrN);

return 0;
}
```

This outputs arrR as: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,100 which is what I want, but
it outputs arrN as: 100,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,100 which I do not understand.

If I remove arrR from the for loop arrN prints how I want

```
    int arrR[100];
int arrN[100];

//function to run the simulation
void runsim(){
    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
        arrN[i] = i;
    }
}


//function to print the array
void printarr(int x[100]){
    for(int i=0;i <= 100;i++){
        cout << x[i] << ", ";
    }
cout << endl;
}


int main(){
runsim();
printarr(arrN);

return 0;
}
```

This outputs arrN as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,100

Interestingly, if I change all the 100's to 10's in the code this problem also goes away even if I keep both arrays in the for loop.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing? I'm sure it's simple because I'm pretty new to C++.  Thank you!

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)` ... problem already: arrays are zero-based in C++.  You are trying to access a region of memory which should not be accessible.

Comment: there's no `x[100]` for you to access

Answer (score 4):

Note the condition of `for` is `i<=100`, equals sign means you will access the array by `arrN[100]`, then get out of the bound. This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), anything is possible. The valid range should be `[0, N)` (`N` = `100`), i.e. `arrN[0]`, …, `arrN[N - 1]` (i.e. `arrN[99]`).

You might want to change all the conditions to `i < 100`.

Comment: Wow thank you! I knew it was going to be something simple.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that array indexing start from `0` instead of `1` ends at `n-1` instead of `n`. Now in your function `runsim()` you are accessing the assigning value `100` to `arrN[100]` and `arrR[100]` which is not possible leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should change the for loop condition

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 // Do something.
}
```

Please note that accessing element out bound will not produce any error as well. For more detail please refer [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)